# Unable to install linux-headers-... on Chromebook that corresponds with the uname -r

Tags: chromebook, dkms

I am running chroot on a chromebook and when I run DKMS I get an error message that it can't find the linux header. When I try to install that header it can't find it.

Comment: `linux-headers*, linux-image*` are updated quite often. Your "uname -r" may not exist any more. So please check if  `linux-image*` requires an upgrade.

Comment: How would one do that in the command prompt?

Comment: Check what's installed : `uname -r` ... and what's available : `apt-cache search linux-image`

Comment: but dkms says I need a certain header

Comment: The headers don't change with an update. The important thing is the exact version match {kernel-image / kernel-headers}.

Comment: there still lacks to be a Linux header 3.18... and the other headers that are listed don't work so I'm stuck, how do I update the Linux image

Comment: `sudo apt upgrade linux-image*` .... Then reboot, to use the updated kernel, and install linux-headers-`uname -r´

Comment: it still shows uname -r to be 3.18... although linux image generic is 4....

Comment: OK, you may have to run `sudo upgate-grub` and `sudo grub-install dev/sdX` ... ( Replace X with actual device.) ... and reboot again to use the updated kernel-image.

Comment: so I am getting an error `grub` `unknown file system`